# change the content of a select option

Tags: jquery, forms, text, html-select

I'd like to change the text shown in a select form, without changing the HTML elements.
This is an example:

```
<select class="myclass" name="myselect">
   <option value="0">1</option>
   <option value="1">2</option>
</select>
```

I would like to change the "2" string into "TWO", for example, like:

```
<option value="1">TWO</option>
```

I'm not able to select the right option inside $('.myclass') and then use the text() function on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specifically know that you want to change the second `option` element within the `select`, you can target it with `:eq()`:

```
$('.myclass option:eq(1)').text('TWO');
```

Note that `eq()` works on a zero-based index, so `0` is the first element, `1` is the second and so on.

Comment: I swear I did not see your answer :)

Comment: @AmmarCSE No problemo - was just seconds between us :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `last-child` selector and self-invoke the function using `(function(){})();` to change the value of second `option` as soon as the DOM is loaded.

```
(function(){
   $('.myclass option:last-child').text("two");  
})();
```